# Regex Youtube iframe parameter for GDPR

Tags: php, regex, wordpress, replace

I have to change in the database all occurence of :

```
<iframe src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/vJcQOmhRPJ1" width="450" height="250" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen="allowfullscreen"></iframe>
```

Or something like that to :

```
<div class="youtube_player" videoID="video_id" width="width" height="height" theme="theme (dark | light)" rel="rel (1 | 0)" controls="controls (1 | 0)" showinfo="showinfo (1 | 0)" autoplay="autoplay (0 | 1)"></div>
```

To be in law with RGPD (en francais) GDPR (in english)

I use Wordpress and Search-Replace-DB-master to change all link in my database with the new div created.

For example :

```
<iframe src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/vJcQOmhRPJ1" width="450" height="250" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen="allowfullscreen"></iframe>

<iframe width="450" height="250" frameborder="0" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/vJcQOmhRPJ2"  allowfullscreen="allowfullscreen"></iframe>
```

Wil become

```
<div class="youtube_player" videoID="vJcQOmhRPJ1" width="450" height="250" theme="dark" rel="1" controls="1" showinfo="1" autoplay="0"></div>
```

Very Thank you for your help

Comment: OK, and what have you tried?

Comment: Can you gureantee the IFrame will always take the same form, the same order is what i mean same attributes.

Answer (score 0):

IF you can gureantee that the Iframe will always be in the form from above.

```
$string = '<iframe width="450" height="250" frameborder="0" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/vJcQOmhRPJ2"  allowfullscreen="allowfullscreen"></iframe>'

$patt ='/^<iframe\swidth="([^"]+)"\sheight="([^"]+)".+src=".+\/(\w+)".+$/';
$replace = '<div class="youtube_player" videoID="$3" width="$1" height="$2" theme="dark" rel="1" controls="1" showinfo="1" autoplay="0"></div>';


$string = preg_Replace($patt,$replace);
```

Outputs

```
<div class="youtube_player" videoID="vJcQOmhRPJ2" width="450" height="250" theme="dark" rel="1" controls="1" showinfo="1" autoplay="0"></div>
```

You can see it here

https://regex101.com/r/Hio6MY/1

If you can't make that guarantee things can get complicated real fast.

**UPDATE**

Here is a version using tokenization, which will handle it no mater the order of the attributes. Remember what I said above

> If you can't make that guarantee things can get complicated real fast.

This is the difference between being simple and being complicated, granted I could write this with less code, but I have this method of tokenization that works extraordinarily well.

```
function parse($subject)
{
    $tokens = [
        'T_SRC'             => 'src\s*=\s*"[^"]+"',
        'T_WIDTH'           => 'width\s*=\s*"[^"]+"',
        'T_HEIGHT'          => 'height\s*=\s*"[^"]+"',
        'T_EOF'             => '\Z',
        'T_UNKNOWN'         => '.+?'
    ];

    $types = array_keys($tokens);
    $patterns = [];
    $lexer_stream = [];
    $result = false;
    foreach ($tokens as $k=>$v){
        $patterns[] = "(?P<$k>$v)";
    }
    $pattern = "/".implode('|', $patterns)."/i";
    if (preg_match_all($pattern, $subject, $matches, PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE)) {
        //print_r($matches);
        foreach ($matches[0] as $key => $value) {
            $match = [];
            foreach ($types as $type) {
                $match = $matches[$type][$key];
                if (is_array($match) && $match[1] != -1) {
                    break;
                }
            }
            $tok  = [
                'content' => $match[0],
                'type' => $type,
                'offset' => $match[1]
            ];
            $lexer_stream[] = $tok;
        }
        //print_r($lexer_stream);
        $result = [];
        while($current = current($lexer_stream)){
            $content = $current['content'];
            $type = $current['type'];
            next($lexer_stream);
            switch($type){
                case 'T_EOF': 
                    return '<div class="youtube_player" '.implode(' ', $result).' rel="1" controls="1" showinfo="1" autoplay="0" ></div>';
                break;
                case 'T_SRC':
                    if(preg_match('/([^\/]+)"$/', $content, $match)){
                        $result[] = 'videoID="'.$match[1].'"';
                    }else{
                        throw new Exception("Failed to parse src $content");
                    }
                break;
                case 'T_HEIGHT':
                case 'T_WIDTH':
                        $result[] = $content;
                break;
                case 'T_UNKNOWN':
                    //ignore
                break;
                default:
                    throw new Exception("Unknown token $type value $content");
            }//end switch
        }//end while lexer

    }//end preg match all
    throw new Exception("Unclosed item $mode for $type value $content");
}//end parse



$string = '<iframe width="450" height="250" frameborder="0" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/vJcQOmhRPJ2"  allowfullscreen="allowfullscreen"></iframe>';


echo parse($string);;
```

Outputs

```
 <div class="youtube_player" videoID="vJcQOmhRPJ2" width="450" height="250" rel="1" controls="1" showinfo="1" autoplay="0" ></div>
```

Try it online
https://3v4l.org/SGu7M

This is a bit too complicated of a process for me to explain in a step by step manner but it should handle any order those attribute are in.  For example, moving the attributes around

```
 //$string = '<iframe width="450" height="250" frameborder="0" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/vJcQOmhRPJ2"  allowfullscreen="allowfullscreen"></iframe>';
 $string = '<iframe frameborder="0" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/vJcQOmhRPJ2" width="450" height="250" allowfullscreen="allowfullscreen"></iframe>';
```

Gives the exact same output...

Last thing is I noticed in your comment you have

```
<div class="youtube_player" videoID="$1" width="$2" height="$3" $4></div>
```

There is no `$4`, at least not in your example of the `<div>` style. There is:

1. videoID from the src attribute
2. width from the width attribute
3. height from the height attribute

There is also no equivalent to these attributes `theme="dark" rel="1" controls="1" showinfo="1" autoplay="0"`  So I just set them to what you had them in the question.  If that is not the case then you will have to update the question with how they are related...

Comment: Thank you ; this is what i've done : 
    Search :
`<iframe width=\"(.{3})\" height=\"(.{3})\" src=\"https:\\/\\/www\.youtube\.com\\/embed\\/(.{11})" (.*)><\\/iframe>`
Replace :
`<div class="youtube_player" videoID="$3" width="$1" height="$2" $4></div>`

    Search : 
`<iframe src=\"https:\\/\\/www\.youtube\.com\\/embed\\/(.{11})" width="(.{3})" height="(.{3})" (.*)><\\/iframe>`
Replace : 
`<div class="youtube_player" videoID="$1" width="$2" height="$3" $4></div>`

Comment: As you can see : https://regex101.com/r/Hio6MY/2
This iframe doesn't work : <iframe src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/2XagclTUiT4" width="450" height="250" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen="allowfullscreen"></iframe>

Comment: as you can see i said `if you can gureantee that the Iframe will always be in the form from above`  I can fix it but I don't have time right now